# TemplateDoesNotExist with Django-Fobi

Tags: python, django

Alright, so I'm not that new to programming, but I still have newbie problems.

I'm using Python 2.7 , Django 1.8

I installed django-fobi around 2 days ago and have been pulling my hair since.
Things are better now, but one error refuses to resolve:

`TemplateDoesNotExist at 127.0.0.1:8000/fobi/forms/create/`  the template is: `bootstrap3/create_form_entry.html`
although the loader does find it:
`project_name/fobi/contrib/themes/bootstrap3/templates/bootstrap3/create_form_entry.html (File exists)`

However, the other templates of fobi are working.

To be honest, I'm not sure if I configuredfobi correctly (newbie issues).

Here are my files:

`project_name/settings.py:`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [(os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, 'templates'))],
        # 'DIRS': [],
        # 'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "fobi.context_processors.theme",  # Important!
                "fobi.context_processors.dynamic_values",  # Optional
                "django.core.context_processors.request"
            ],
             'loaders': [
                 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                 'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
             ],
            # 'debug': DEBUG_TEMPLATE,
        },
    },
]
```

And I copied the fobi folder from `https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-fobi/tree/master/src` and put it at `project_name/fobi`

Initially, when I did not have the full fobi folder copied, I had just a few templates copied to `project_name/templates/bootstrap3/create_form_entry.html`, and the template loaded, but then the reversed url `fobi_theme.create_form_entry` didn't work.

All migrations are applied and the apps are added in INSTALLED_APPS.

Please, help and thank you in advance.

Comment: This `/fobi/forms/create/` is not the same directory you specify as containing the file. Why is your app looking here? Also, it is a good idea in general to use Python3 with Django going forward, just an FYI.

Comment: Sorry, `/fobi/forms/create/` is the url. I'll make that more clear in the question. I agree about Python3. This project was done for a course on Python2.7, so I just stuck with it.

Comment: I'm saying that is your problem

Comment: The location you verify is not the same as the error. Does the template exist in that location?

Comment: Something should be wrong with your settings. I run the django-fobi example project, with installed django-fobi and example requirements (for django 1.8) with no problems on Python 2. Compare your settings with settings of example project.